# Custom parameters in project template for Visual C++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project-template

I would like to create a custom template for project in Visual C++ 2012.

I know that I can create a project and then use `File->Export template...`.

But how to achive the checkboxes, selects or whatever like that in the template, so the user can customize the project?

E.g. My custom project will always include some libraries etc., but I want to show the 3 check-boxes: "include 2d engine", "include 3d engine" and "include internet module" - based on it, I will or won't include some more libraries and set defines.

In other words, for the Win32 you have:
[image]

And for MyProjectTemplate, I would like to have 3 checkboxes with own labels (just like "empty project", "export symbols" and "precompiled header" on the image above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a [custom wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhceedxx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can create one by creating a new project using the "custom wizard" project wizard under Visual C++ -> General.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzU3w.jpg) is a screenshot of the wizard it generates by default.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you :)